# XSLT assign variable value from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

From an XML document:

```
<samlp:Response ID="_f9daea33-e32a-4dde-beb4-d5227690b1a3" Version="2.0"
    IssueInstant="2015-07-30T15:06:58.874Z"
    Destination="https://domain.net/Login/PAuthentication.aspx?configSet=SAML"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
        >urn:jh:identityprovider</saml:Issuer>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="#_f9daea33-e32a-4dde-beb4-d5227690b1a3">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="#default samlp saml ds xs xsi"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    </Transform>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>uL1LoegsT53UGJE/HQqG9VW1Mnc=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>ifdW4P9/</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIIHwzCCBaugAwIBAgIKeH+</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion Version="2.0" ID="_b54ca592-4401-4107-a426-281918091842"
        IssueInstant="2015-07-30T15:06:58.898Z" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <saml:Issuer>urn:jh:identityprovider</saml:Issuer>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"
                >ZQA|brandtest</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2015-07-30T16:06:59.331Z"
                    Recipient="https://jacksonhewitt.brandmuscle.net/Login/PAuthentication.aspx?configSet=SAML"
                 />
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2015-07-30T14:06:59.331Z"
            NotOnOrAfter="2015-07-30T16:06:59.331Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>https://domain.net/Login/PAuthentication.aspx?configSet=SAML</saml:Audience>
                <saml:Audience>https://domain.net/</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="Phone"
                NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue>867-5309</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="Phone2"
                NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
                <saml:AttributeValue>555-1212</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
        </saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2015-07-30T15:06:59.335Z">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

XSLT Document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <AUTHENTICATOR>
        <USERINFO>
            <xsl:for-each select="/samlp:Response/*[local-name() = 'Assertion']/*[local-name() = 'AttributeStatement']/*">

            <!--This one works -->  
            <xsl:if test="(@Name='Phone')">
                <xsl:variable name="phone" select="*[local-name() = 'AttributeValue']" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$phone"/>
            </xsl:if>

            <!--This one doesn't work -->
            <xsl:variable name="phone2" select="samlp:AttributeValue[../@Name = 'Phone2']" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$phone2"/>

            </xsl:for-each>

            </USERINFO>
        </AUTHENTICATOR>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When trying to output the value of the variable, it is empty. I'm guessing my 'select' syntax in the xsl:variable is incorrect?

I am able to get it to work like using the code below, but I don't want to have to use the 'if'.

```
    <xsl:if test="(@Name='Phone')">
       <xsl:variable name="phone" select="*[local-name() = 'AttributeValue']" />
       <xsl:value-of select="$phone"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have subsequently updated my answer with some comments on your last code snippet and indeed you are right, there is no need to use `xsl:if`.

Comment: Could be a namespace problem; is the `saml` prefix in the input bound to the same URI as the `samlp` prefix in the stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

The key issue here is what the focus is. While the [answer of proycon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32764477/111575) shows that you have used the attribute axis (with `@`), to access an element node, and that you forgot to use the namespace prefix, if you do not get the value, the focus may not be on `saml:Attribute`. Without seeing the rest of the code, it is hard to tell where it goes wrong.

Suppose you have this:

```
<xsl:template match="Attribute">
   <!-- your variable here -->
```

then the template would never be matched, because it is not in the correct namespace. But even if you fix this to be `match="saml:Attribute"`, your variable starts with `*`, which is short for `child::*`, and there is no child with an attribute `Name` under `saml:Attribute`.

Suppose you have this:

```
<xsl:template match="saml:Xyz">
   <!-- your variable here -->
```

then your focus is on some other node `Xyz`.

To fix it, you need the surrounding focus-setting expression (`xsl:template` or `xsl:for-each`) to select the parent of `saml:Attribute`, or you need to address the expression itself if the focus is something else. The following would work, depending on the rest of your stylesheet (i.e., whether or not you applied templates to this node or not, here shown as a shallow-skip pattern):

Only outputs the phone number(s):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="saml:Attribute[@Name = 'Phone']">
        <xsl:variable name="phone" select="saml:AttributeValue" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$phone" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Update (after your Q. update)

While I typed my answer, you said you did not want to use `xsl:if` and that you got it to work with the following code:

```
<xsl:if test="(@Name='Phone')">
   <xsl:variable name="phone" select="*[local-name() = 'AttributeValue']" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$phone"/>
</xsl:if>
```

A few points of interest:

1. Unless there is no way around it, do not use `local-name()`, if a direct NameTest suffices, in this case `saml:AttributeValue` (don't forget to add the namespace to the `xsl:stylesheet` root element)
2. The parentheses in the `xsl:if/@test` are redundant
3. You are right, you do not need `xsl:if`. You can simply change your variable to point to `saml:AttributeValue[../@Name='Phone']`, which will select nothingness, unless its parent has `Phone` in the `Name` attribute. 0. In other words, this is the same:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="phone" select="saml:AttributeValue[../@Name = 'Phone']" />
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am still unable to get this to work. I updated my original post to include the complete XSLT file for reference. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @pixel, you second one has `.. /@Name = 'Phone2' `, which is not in your data, it has value "Phone"...

Comment: 'Phone2' is in the data, was just not added to my post. Edited it to include. Thanks.

Comment: @PixelPaul, well, with your given data and the latest version you posted in your question, it "just works". So locally there must be something different. Check it online to see: http://xsltransform.net/ej9EGbL

Comment: I appreciate the help. Your test link does work, but when I use the full XML document it does not. Edited original post to include complete XML. I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: @PixelPaul, you got the namespaces mixed up, using `samlp` where `saml` was needed. Since these namespace prefixes are easy to confuse, I have changed them (only in the XSLT) to be `assert` and `prototocol`, so that they stand out better. I also removed you `local-name()`, because that confused things even more, see: http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYhQ

Comment: Thank you once again! Is there a way to get the 'Phone2' to work without changing the namespaces and only the '<xsl:variable>' line of code?

Answer (score 0):

AttributeValue is an element and not an attribute, despite its misleading name ;)  So use `*[@Name='Phone']/saml:AttributeValue`

Comment: Still not outputting a value.

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you don't want to use prefixes and don't want to use **if**, you can use the following:

```
        <xsl:variable name="phone" select="*[@Name='Phone']/*[local-name() = 'AttributeValue']" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$phone"/>
```